# Does Mockito support @Any @Inject Instance<> interface?

Tags: junit, mockito, instance, ejb-3.0, inject

I have a init() method that use injected private instance<>. How can I test this class using JUnit or Mockito? I tried to make some fake class and add them to a list and set this list to my private field but I have this error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.enterprise.inject.Instance field ......

MyClass is:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class HandlerManager {

    @Any
    @Inject
    private Instance<RollbackHandler<RollbackData>> handlers;

    private RollbackHandler<RollbackData> rollbackHandler;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        for (RollbackHandler<RollbackData> bean : handlers) {

//do something

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any annotation is not processed by frameworks, unless you use custom work. you will have to define all those dependencies as mocks in your test using @Mock and call injectMocks() from before test methods such as setup(). It is a multi part problem.

- Use constructor injection, field injection is evil. you still will be able to annotate your constructor with @Inject.

Comment: I tried to mock my injected instance but I cant then I tried to make a list of fake class of Instance<RollbackHandler<RollbackData>> and add it into instance but I cant. could you pleas give me an example of mocking and testing private Instance<RollbackHandler<RollbackData>>? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
when(provider.iterator()).thenReturn(list.iterator);
```

works for me.

Comment: This is on Low Quality Post review queue because it needs an explanation besides just code.  Pls. edit and add brief description.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary list with concrete implementations of the `RollbackHandler`, and mock the `iterator()` method of your `Instance<RollbackHandler<RollbackData>>` object so that it returns the iterator of the temporary list.

Example:

```
private void mockIterator() {
    Instance<RollbackHandler<RollbackData>> handlers = mock(Instance.class);    
    List<RollbackHandler<RollbackData>> handlersList = Collections.singletonList(new RollbackHandlerImpl<>());
    
    when(handlers.iterator()).thenReturn(handlersList.iterator());
}
```